# C#, How to Traverse all drive and folder to copy image and paste them in a specific folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, traversal, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

my project was a image gallery using asp.net.
Initially when then the project load first time i need to copy all the images in the computer and paste them in a folder named  Data.

here is my project link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sr3qhaamiiwk0di/Gallary_temp.zip?dl=0
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BynGaI0gi3mrOEtweWlWOEdmSFE/view?usp=sharing

Of course, code must be in c#

Comment: Please don't use links to external websites. Please follow [these rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting your code.

Comment: Copying all images to a new folder is a terrible idea. I have over half a terabyte of photos. I don't want my image viewer to immediately use up another half terabyte. Not to mention how long that would take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of copying the image from hard drive to your location every time, it is better you save the file location in DB and call them when ever you require.